# Fast eclipse mode for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, editor, highlighting

Does anybody know of a fast PHP mode for eclipse?  I have tried the Aptana PHP mode, and PDT, but neither can place a character in under a second, which is no way to write code.

Its probably due to my editing on a network drive, but it seems silly that an editor would depend so heavily on the hard drive.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the problem by copying the project to a local drive and opening it locally? Then you'll know if the slowness is due to the network or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable Code Folding under Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Code Folding. If file is larger than 200 lines of code, this feature cause Eclipse to run really slow!

They said that this bug is fixed back in 2008. but I still have this problem :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! Apparently the larger the project the slower this feature becomes. Yet another 'opportunity for improvement' in PDT ;P

Answer (score 1):

I give my vote to Netbeans-PHP. But my prediction is it will be the same as Eclipse because these IDEs need to read PHP source files from HDD to create autocompletion database. And since your files are in network drive it will sure slow. Maybe you should consider using some version control software which can pull a source copy from network. So it will not slow down the IDE much.

Answer (score 1):

Is Eclipse running from the network drive or is the file you are editing on the network drive. I run Eclipse with PHPEclipse all the time and the files I edit are on a network drive which mounts a Samba share on a Linux virtual machine and I have no problems. Eclipse depends on Java and it also takes a lot of memory. You may want to check that Java is working properly and that you aren't running out of memory. Or do an experiment and edit a file that is not on a network drive and see if it is any faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard netbeans has great PHP support.

Comment: And I used it. Its good. Can't say great as I didn't use any other editor for PHP. By the way, I spit Java mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse/PDT every day and it works fine. I guess I don't know what 'place a character in under a second' means cause I don't see any sort of delay entering code at all...

Comment: I think he means the files are in network drive. And Eclipse read & write heavily on the nw drive which makes it too slow/unresponsive to code.